# "ls" sees different files in the same folder on the same machine in two different terminals. How is this even possible?

Tags: bash, ssh, ls

A very strange situation occurred to me just now. I'm managing some stuff on a cloud VM running Ubuntu over SSH in a TMUX session. Right now, I have two panes open, which see different files even though they are on the same (virtual) PC:

**Terminal #1:**

```bash
pan@gergo-skynet-master:~/shared/Lammps/new-lengths/125$ pwd                                                                            
/home/pan/shared/Lammps/new-lengths/125                                                                                                 
pan@gergo-skynet-master:~/shared/Lammps/new-lengths/125$ hostname
gergo-skynet-master.desy.de                                                                                                             
pan@gergo-skynet-master:~/shared/Lammps/new-lengths/125$ ls                                                                             
*****_annotated.in  data.lammps             ******.py  process         rg           run1.restart                                                                                                                                           
SHAKE_10             dump_*****.lammpstrj  lammps.out   process.py      rg.dump      ******.data                                                                                                                                        
SHAKE_7              extract_data.sh         log.lammps   process_all.py  run.restart                                                                                                                                                         
pan@gergo-skynet-master:~/shared/Lammps/new-lengths/125$
```

**Terminal #2:**

```bash
pan@gergo-skynet-master:~/shared/Lammps/new-lengths/125$ pwd
/home/pan/shared/Lammps/new-lengths/125
pan@gergo-skynet-master:~/shared/Lammps/new-lengths/125$ hostname
gergo-skynet-master.desy.de
pan@gergo-skynet-master:~/shared/Lammps/new-lengths/125$ ls
*****_annotated.in  extract_data.sh  *****.py  process  process.py  process_all.py  ******.data
pan@gergo-skynet-master:~/shared/Lammps/new-lengths/125$
```

I had to censor some filenames, but you get the idea.

[image: see here]

Things I confirmed:

- I'm at the exact same filesystem location.
- `ls` is not aliased in either of the terminals.
- I'm the same user in both terminal, on the same machine.

I'm sure the correct one is the upper one, but I'm very puzzled how is this even possible? Even after cd-ing around in the lower terminal, it won't see all the files the upper one does. I don't even know where to start debugging the situation. I'm afraid that at a later point I also won't see some important files because of the same issue, so I really want to figure out what happened before I close the lower terminal.

Do you have any idea? What additional info would be useful?

Comment: Did you try to cd around in the upper terminal too? One way to get that would be if you've renamed the directory at some point (e.g. `mkdir foo; cd foo; echo > hello.txt` in one terminal, then `mv foo bar; mkdir foo; cd foo` in another, and both would show `.../foo` as the path, and an `ls` in one would list `hello.txt`, even though the directory now named `foo` doesn't contain it.)

Comment: Running `stat .` in both should show if they're actually the same directory (look at the device and inode numbers)

Comment: same as @ilkkachu, test directory's inode using `ls -di .`

Comment: Where you use `pwd` please try `/bin/pwd`. I think you'll see they are now different directories

Comment: @roaima What... you're right! I'm in a different directory in #1 than shown by both PS1 and by `pwd`. How is this possible? I thought `pwd` is the same as `/bin/pwd`. It is not aliased.

Comment: @Neinstein it's a mismatch between what your shell (`bash`?) _thinks_ is the current directory (repesented to you with `pwd` or the `$PWD` variable) and the _actual_ directory (discovered on request by `/bin/pwd`). Most of the time they are the same. Symbolic links or parent directory renames can confuse it.

Comment: The same problem on SU: [*File system contents sometimes not synced in some bash terminals*](https://superuser.com/q/1814325/432690).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things that could cause this behavior. Consider this sequence of events:

1. Create a directory, change into it, and create some files:

   ```
   mkdir /tmp/dir1
   cd /tmp/dir1
   touch file{1,2,3}
   ```
2. From another terminal, rename the directory, create a new directory
   with the original name, and populate it with different files:

   ```
   mv /tmp/dir1 /tmp/dir2
   mkdir /tmp/dir1
   cd /tmp/dir1
   touch file{4,5,6}
   ```
3. Now in the original terminal we see:

   ```
   $ pwd
   /tmp/dir1
   $ ls
   file1 file2 file3
   ```

   And in the second terminal we see:

   ```
   $ pwd
   /tmp/dir1
   $ ls
   file4 file5 file6
   ```

---

There are other situations which could produce this behavior (e.g., running in separate mount namespaces in both terminals -- perhaps in containers), but the above seems the most likely explanation.

Comment: That could be detected with the i-node number of the directory, something like `ls -id ./.` on each terminal. If the inode numbers differ, each terminal is in a different directory.

Comment: Sure. Also, simply running `cd $PWD` in both terminals would eliminate this particular discrepancy.

Comment: Why does this happen? Shouldn't `pwd` find out that the current directory is now different? And why does `/bin/pwd` print the correct name while `pwd` doesn't, as suggested by @roamia in a comment?

Comment: `pwd` is a bash built-in, while `/bin/pwd` is an external command. The `pwd` built-in is taking advantage of what bash "knows" about your current location based on your `cd` commands, while `/bin/pwd` has to calculate this.

Comment: Accepted as this was exactly what happened. At one point I copied the displayed directory and renamed it, #1 was in the renamed copy.

Comment: @larsks Thanks. In this case `alias pwd=/bin/pwd` should prevent this problem ever occuring again.

Comment: As would using `pwd -P`